# Yacc/Bison for Verilog hierarchical and arrayed identifiers

Tags: yacc, jison

I'm trying to parse identifiers in the Verilog language. The full grammar is [here](http://www.syncad.com/VeriLogger_bnf_Syntax_Verilog_2001.htm).

They can have the forms below:

```
name
name[index]
name[start:stop]
name[index][start:stop]
name.(any of the above)
name[index].(any of the above)
name[index].name[index]... .name[index][start:stop]
```

Or in EMBF format:

```
(name ([index])?)+ ([start:stop])?
```

Here `name` is a typical identifier as in most programming languages, while `index`, `start` and `stop` are integer.

I'm new to yacc (I'm actually using Jison) but I'm not sure that this can be correctly interpreted at all with the single lookahead token limitation. If `name` and `[` are in the stack, it cannot tell the difference between index and start.

This is my grammar so far:

```
primary 
: number
| hierarchical_identifier bracketted_range_expression
| hierarchical_identifier
;

primary 
: number
| hierarchical_identifier
| hierarchical_identifier bracketted_range_expression
;

hierarchical_identifier
: IDENTIFIER
| IDENTIFIER '[' UNSIGNED_NUMBER ']'
| hierarchical_identifier '.' IDENTIFIER
| hierarchical_identifier '.' IDENTIFIER '[' UNSIGNED_NUMBER ']'
;

bracketted_range_expression
: '[' range_expression ']';

range_expression
: UNSIGNED_NUMBER ':' UNSIGNED_NUMBER
```

Which yields several shift/reduce and reduce/reduce errors, and it simply does not want to parse something line `foo[1:0]`. It expects a `]` instead fo the `:`. Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. With your grammar, `hierarchical_identifier` must be reduced before the parser can start scanning `bracketed_range_expression`, but it cannot know whether the `[` following an `IDENTIFIER` starts a `bracketed_range_expression` (in which case the reduction is necessary) or is the `[` in `'[' UNSIGNED_NUMBER ']'` (in which case it should be shifted).

With bison, we could solve this using a GLR parser, but with jison we're limited to LALR(1). Fortunately, the language is still LALR(1); all that is needed is to defer the shift/reduce decision by expanding some nonterminals and reducing them later.

Unfortunately, the result is a bit ugly because it requires a certain amount of duplication. Because we need to always be able to shift the `[`, we end up "denormalizing" the grammar (to borrow a term from database design).

Here's one solution, tested with [the jison on-line tool](https://zaach.github.io/jison/try/). (The actions were only intended to show that the grammar attaches the range to the entire hierarchical list, and not just to the last identifier in the list.)

```
/* lexical grammar */
%lex
%%

\s+                   /* skip whitespace */
[0-9]+                return 'NUMBER'
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*  return 'IDENTIFIER'
.                     return yytext[0]
<<EOF>>               return 'EOF'

/lex

%start expr

%% /* language grammar */

expr   : primary EOF { return $1; }
       ;

primary: NUMBER
       | hierarchical_identifier
       | hierarchical_identifier_with_range
       ;

indexed_identifier
       : IDENTIFIER '[' NUMBER ']' { $$ = { "id": $1, "idx": $3}; } ;

postfix_range
       : '[' NUMBER ':' NUMBER ']' { $$ = [ $2, $4 ]; } ;

hierarchical_identifier
       : IDENTIFIER         { $$ = []; $$.push({ "id": $1}); }
       | indexed_identifier { $$ = [ $1 ]; }
       | hierarchical_identifier '.' IDENTIFIER
                            { $$ = $1; $$.push({ "id": $3}); }
       | hierarchical_identifier '.' indexed_identifier
                            { $$ = $1; $$.push($3); }
       ;

hierarchical_identifier_with_range
       : IDENTIFIER postfix_range
                            { $$ = { "idlist": [{"id": $1}],
                                     "lo": $2[0], "hi": $2[1]}; }
       | indexed_identifier postfix_range
                            { $$ = { "idlist": [$1],
                                     "lo": $2[0], "hi": $2[1]}; }
       | hierarchical_identifier '.' IDENTIFIER postfix_range
                            { $1.push({"id": $3});
                              $$ = { "idlist": $1,
                                     "lo": $4[0], "hi": $4[1]}; }
       | hierarchical_identifier '.' indexed_identifier postfix_range
                            { $1.push($3);
                              $$ = { "idlist": $1,
                                     "lo": $4[0], "hi": $4[1]}; }
       ;
```

If you eventually plan to use bison, you will probably find that a GLR parser is easier, without adding too much parsing overhead (since your grammar really is unambiguous).

Comment: +1 This works. Could you please explain the logic behind your changes? I might need to fix multiple problems like this and I'm not fully grasping the technique for solving the generic problem.

Comment: @jpcgt: The basic principle is the one I outlined: if a single token lookahead is not sufficient, work out how to defer the decision. If there is a known finite lookahead, this can be done mechanically, but you can often do better with a bit of ingenuity. Here, the grammar is LR(3), so the mechanical solution would work. All I did was to extend the productions which need more lookahead until the conflict can be resolved.

Comment: @jpcgt: But if at all possible, use a GLR parser and avoid the grammar manipulation.

Comment: I'm really new at this so I'm having trouble understanding how the decision is being deferred. What do you mean by extending the productions? Breaking them into smaller pieces? I know, this might require a lengthy explanation, so perhaps you could point me to a good article? I'm stick with Jison at this time, but eventually might move to Bison for production.

Comment: @jpcgt: Compare what I wrote with what you wrote. You had the right-hand side: `hierarchical_identifier bracketted_range_expression`; that doesn't work because it is not possible to know whether to reduce `hierarchical_identifier` at the point when it might need to be reduced. So I introduce a new non-terminal, `hierarchical_identifier_with_range`, and expand out enough of the production so that shift/reduce decisions can be made. I don't know how to explain it better; after you've done it a few times, it becomes easier. I can point you to other examples, though.

Comment: @jpcgt: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19340247/1566221 http://stackoverflow.com/a/16931641/1566221 http://stackoverflow.com/a/26189559/1566221